# Collapsing one col by another in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where the top looks like:

```
>head(transposed_label,20)
      val index
 [1,] "0" "1"  
 [2,] "1" "1"  
 [3,] "0" "1"  
 [4,] "0" "2"  
 [5,] "1" "2"  
 [6,] "0" "2"  
 [7,] "1" "3"  
 [8,] "0" "3"  
 [9,] "0" "3"  
[10,] "0" "4"  
[11,] "1" "4"  
[12,] "0" "4"  
[13,] "0" "5"  
[14,] "0" "5"  
[15,] "1" "5"  
[16,] "0" "6"  
[17,] "1" "6"  
[18,] "0" "6"  
[19,] "0" "7"  
[20,] "0" "7"
```

I want to collapse the values in "val" by "index"

I have tried:

```
>library(dplyr)

>new <- as.data.frame(transposed_label) %>% group_by(as.numeric(index))
%>% summarise(val = paste(val, collapse =","))
```

But this gives me:

```
head(new,10)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      as.numeric(index) val  
                <dbl> <chr>
1                   1 0,1,0
2                   2 1,0,0
3                   3 0,1,0
4                   4 0,1,0
5                   5 1,0,0
6                   6 0,1,0
7                   7 0,1,0
8                   8 0,0,1
9                   9 0,0,1
10                  10 1,0,0
```

When I would expect something like:

```
1 0,1,0
2 0,1,0
3 1,0,0
4 0,1,0
5 0,0,1

etc
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Since there seems to be a data types issue here, it's much more helpful if you post the results of `dput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the columns were `factor` with `as.data.frame` and the values got were the integer coersion.  So, if we use the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, should solve the issue

```
as.data.frame(transposed_label, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```